# Hover highlight for tables not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'm following the example [Bootstrap's site](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/) and I see that the table looks differently when I add the class *table* to my table tag but there's nothing new going on when I add *table-hover*. So both of the following lines produce the same L&F (none of which highlights the row that I hover above).

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<table class="table">
```

What can I be missing?

There are no errors reported in the console, it works definitely on the page linked to, I can't see anything informative when goolearching. I'm relying on the minified files (all four CSS's and one JS plus Tether).

Comment: Does your table have a tbody tag?

Comment: It has *table*, *tr*, *th* and *td*. I assumed that *tbody* was the combination of those... Are you saying that I need to explicitly add *tbody*?!

Comment: Yes. The row is being targeted by: .table-hover tbody tr:hover. Without a tbody tag, no row will get targeted. You can add a tbody to your HTML markup, or just change the css to .table-hover tr:hover. I'd go with the first option though.

Comment: For anyone else reading this answer, also you set a background color using style="" on the TR the hover won't work. That's what got me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS for table-hover is

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
   ...some change
}
```

Make sure your HTML has a `tbody` tag:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also consider including a `thead` if your table has a header. Note that `.table-hover` won't target rows in `thead`.

If you want to affect the rows on hover without changing your markup, you can try adding:

```
.table-hover tr:hover {
   ...some change
}
```

Comment: Very well explained and exemplified. +1